# EntityManagerFactory stores metadata for all the classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Why `EntityManagerFactory` stores meta data for all the classes? It can also be stored in `EntityManager` cause anyways `EntityManager` is the one which mostly interacts with the Entities and manages the lifecycle of entity?

Comment: Why would it store persistence-unit level information in an EntityManager when you can / should have multiple EntityManagers per application? makes no sense at all ...

Comment: @NeilStockton ah! you're right! but why does it store metadata afterall?

Comment: why wouldn't it store metadata for the entities? you expect it to re-read it every time some JPA operation is performed?!